# How to completely disassociate iMessage from my device?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, messages

I have an older iPhone that I was thinking about selling soon in order to get a new one. I've set up iMessaging on the device.  Normally I would just erase the phone a couple of times and be done with it.  But recently, [there has been exposed a glitch](http://www.slashgear.com/apple-imessage-bug-allows-others-to-spy-on-your-convos-05212116/) in iMessaging whereby users continue to receive other user's iMessages, *even after the sim card is removed, and the phone is erased.*

So I'm curious: is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a workaround for this issue. You change your iCloud account password and enter it on the new device. After that the old device will have your old password, reboot the old device and you have completely circumvented the issue.

Works perfectly for me.

Comment: Yep it worked for me :)

Comment: There is a residual risk with this method. If one day you change back your iCloud password to this old one, then your old device will recover access to your iMessages.

Answer (score 10):

Go into Settings -> Messages and halfway down choose Send and Receive.
Tap your AppleID on the top of the page, sign out, and let the new guy sign his or her self in.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: On the device, go to Settings then iMessage then tap on 'Receive at'. Tap the Apple ID at the top and you get the option to 'Sign out'. No need to change passwords. Should stop messages on that device until you sign in again.

Answer (score 1):

This drove me mad... finally worked it out. Not icloud settings but imessage settings:

1. Tap **Settings**
2. Then **Messages**
3. Then **"Send & Receive"**
4. Ensure that at the top, next to **"Apple ID"**, your ID information is
   displayed.

If it is still showing someone else's Apple ID, tap it, and choose **Sign Out**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Unregister the old device by logging in here: https://supportprofile.apple.com

Comment: I don't see an option to unregister a device from iMessage on this page, could you please explain a bit more in detail?

Answer (score -2):

In settings go to messages then select receive at. From there unclick the phone number and this will stop iMessage sharing.. My husband n I share the same apple ID and this fixed the problem with the iOS 6 upgrade     No need to turn iMessage off.   I tested it n it works.  Now remember it only takes a click to start reading each others iMessages again ... This is where trust comes to play...