# SMS still sends to group via iMessage after disabling

Tags: iphone, messages

I recently switched from my iPhone to an Android. Before removing my SIM card, I disabled iMessage in settings. My Macbook Messages app shows it as disabled, and the online service to disable a number does as well. When iOS users send me a message directly, it is sent as SMS. However, when I am added to a group iMessage it doesn't change to MMS. Any ideas?

EDIT:

I found out that deleting the conversation history and starting a new one caused it to use MMS. Still hoping there's a general solution to telling everyone to delete their history.

Answer (score 1):

A little trick: change your iCloud password. Then all of apple services can NOT work properly. 
See the relevant-support here: [How to completely disassociate iMessage from my device?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46050/how-to-completely-disassociate-imessage-from-my-device)