# How to disassociate AppleID from an old iPhone?

Tags: iphone, apple-id

I have given my grandson my old iPhone, but all the messages sent to my current one are still being received by that phone as well, even though it's a different number.

How can I prevent my iPhone to do so?

Comment: Did you erase the iPhone before you gave it to him (reset and erase all items)?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the *correct* answer for you. It is currently the [highest-voted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/64933/150997) to a very similar question which was asked previously.

**Go into Settings > Messages and halfway down choose Send and Receive. Tap your AppleID on the top of the page, then choose Sign Out.**

If you really are giving away your phone there are several other places you ought to sign out from as well:

- Settings > FaceTime
- Settings > iCloud
- Settings > iTunes and App Store

If you'd prefer to reset the phone to its factory defaults, wiping all your data, apps, music, etcetera, then use Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content And Settings. Then the phone will be brand new like you just bought it from the shop.

Answer (score -1):

Sign out of iCloud on the iPhone.

Excerpt from Apple:

On your iOS device: Go to Settings > iCloud, then at the bottom of the screen, tap Sign Out.

Source: https://support.apple.com/kb/ph2613

Try this and report the results.

Comment: Not enough. See https://support.apple.com/HT201351